# Mediapipe samples are not compatible with latest versions of 'androidx.camera'

Tags: android, android-jetpack, tensorflow-lite, android-camerax

I'm trying to use this framework with own model and it works well.

My issue is about versions of `androidx.camera`, I faced with issue that
[CameraXPreviewHelper](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/java/com/google/mediapipe/components/CameraXPreviewHelper.java) depends on old version of **camera-core**.

> androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha06

This is part of main method to open camera from helper class.

```
public void startCamera(Activity context, CameraFacing cameraFacing, SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    LensFacing cameraLensFacing = cameraFacing == 
                CameraFacing.FRONT ? LensFacing.FRONT : LensFacing.BACK;
    PreviewConfig previewConfig = (new Builder()).setLensFacing(cameraLensFacing)
                .setTargetResolution(TARGET_SIZE).build();
    this.preview = new Preview(previewConfig);

    this.preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener((previewOutput) -> { 
         .
         .
         .
}
```

Unfortunately `preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener` do not exist anymore ([removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c6e1e60f6a115bdf4eae4758db9e76613bd4cf77%5E%21/#F6) since 1.0.0-alpha07).

What is the correct way to implement camera preview with mediapipe based on latest camera api? (or any other api)

Reported [issue](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/472) as well

**update**:
Would be grateful if someone could mark it with tag [mediapipe], Thanks!

Comment: That use-case might be an `ImageAnalyzer`.

Comment: Already investigated that option. Thanks for comment anyway @MartinZeitler